# Apostol Analysis Book Theorem Understanding

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I was going through Mathematical Analysis by Apostol and came across the Theorem that is built from the following Axiom.

Axiom 6: Exactly one of the relations x=y, x>y or x<y holds

```
Theorem 1.1 Given Real Numbers a and b such that

a ≤ b + ε for every ε > 0 (1)

Then a ≤ b

Proof: if b < a , then inequality (1) is violated for ε = (a-b)/2 because



b + ε = b + (a-b)/2 = (a+b)/2 < (a+a)/2 = a

Therefore by Axiom 6 we must have a ≤ b
```

So this is my understanding for the above proof

In order to prove a ≤ b , we prove the contradiction b < a is not true by the following.

```
WE take b < a and add to b ε = (a-b)/2

This produces b + (a-b)/2 which is (a+b)/2

We then compare (a+b)/2 with something bigger than (a+b)/2. Since b<a we use (a+a)/2 which is automatically greater than (a+b)/2 since b<a.



(a+a)/2 is now a

And we just proved that b + ε < a , but since we are given a ≤ b + ε for every ε > 0 , b + ε < a cannot be true
```

Hence

```
Therefore by Axiom 6 we must have a ≤ b
```

Is my understanding for the above correct ?

Comment: Yes, it is correct what you've understood.

Answer (score 1):

To prove the implication $$p\implies q$$
it is sometimes easier to prove the equivalent
$$\lnot q \implies \lnot p$$

here
$$p = \forall \epsilon>0\;\; a\le b+\epsilon$$

$$q = a\le b$$

$$\lnot q = a> b$$

$$\lnot p = \exists \epsilon>0 \;\; :\;\;a> b+\epsilon$$

You proved that
$$a>b \implies$$

$$a-b>\frac{a-b}{2} \implies$$
$$a>b+\frac{a-b}{2} \implies$$
$$\exists \epsilon>0 (=\frac{a-b}{2})\;\; :\;\; a>b+\epsilon$$
Done.

Comment: Thank you for the clear clarification. But in this case, are we proving  ¬p and then since  a ≤ b + ε for every ε > 0 (1), we are disassociating  ¬p and approving p       ?

Comment: The negation of for every $\epsilon$ is : There exists At least ONE \epsilon$.